# How to use Regex to check if the string is a date F#

Tags: f#

I am looking to use regex commands that can tell if is a date or not listed below are dates in the format that they will appear. Now I need to implement pattern matching so I am able to differentiate which is a date or not.

```
15-Aug-20
123
9-Sept-20
352
1-Jan-21
```

Comment: Why use regex at all instead of `DateTime.Parse`? Besides, what dates are those? 1915? 1920? There's absolutely no excuse for two-digit years. Not in the very year when [major banks' systems crashed](https://www.theregister.com/2020/01/02/lloyds_outage/) because they used two-digit years

Comment: No, you don't need either pattern matching or regular expressions. You need the parser already available in `DateTime.Parse`. And a proper string. *All* those values should be considered invalid

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, you should avoid using ambiguous non-standard date formats and just use one that can be parsed with the built-in `DateTime.Parse`.

However, if you are trying to parse bad data produced by someone else (i.e. "real world data science" :-)), then the following regular expression works for the samples you provided:

```
Regex.Match(sample, "(\d{1,2})-(Aug|Sept|Jan)-(\d{2})")
```

This conservatively looks for 1-2 digits, followed by one of the pre-defined months (you'll need to add other months you want to support) and exactly two digits. Testing this with your sample data:

```
let data = 
  [ "15-Aug-20"; "123"; "9-Sept-20"; "352"; "1-Jan-21" ]


for d in data do
  let res = Regex.Match(d, "(\d{1,2})-(Aug|Sept|Jan)-(\d{2})")
  if res.Success then 
    printfn "%s is a date. Day: %d, Month: %s, Year: %d" d 
      (int res.Groups.[1].Value)
      (res.Groups.[2].Value)
      (int res.Groups.[3].Value)
```